# Extra PropertyChanged needed after INotifyTaskCompletion completes its task

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, async-await, inotifytaskcompletion

I use the method of [this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) (last paragraph) with `INotifyTaskCompletion` to have async properties in a view-model. It works nicely but I had to adapt it somewhat and there lies my question - whether I did it correctly or not.

View-model:

```
async Task<ObservableCollection<string>> GetInstancesAsync()
{
    var instances = await TaskEx.Run(new Func<List<string>>(() => Agent.GetInstances()));
    return new ObservableCollection<string>(instances);
}
public INotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<string>> InstancesAsync { get; private set; }
string instance;
public string Instance
{
    get { return instance; }
    set
    {
        instance = value;
        ProjectsAsync = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetProjetsAsync(value));
        raisePropertyChanged("ProjectsAsync");
    }
}
```

In the constructor I start off:

```
InstancesAsync = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetInstancesAsync(value));
raisePropertyChanged("InstancesAsync");
```

The databinding is simply `ItemsSource="{Binding InstancesAsync.Result}"`.
The implementation of `INotifyTaskCompletion<TResult>` is not complicated, abbreviated: `task.ContinueWith(t => { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result")); };`

My understanding is as follows: after starting the task, `raisePropertyChanged("InstancesAsync")` has the effect that wpf tries to find `InstancesAsync.Result`. It finds `InstancesAsync` because this object is instantiated *before* the task starts, but Result is *null*. After completion of the task, wpf receives `PropertyChanged("Result")` and via the *existing* accessor `InstancesAsync` `Result` is now found.
The ItemsSource in wpf is populated and now wpf must trigger the Binding for SelectedItem and in this way go to property `Instance`. Because in my case, there another async property task is started.
For that to happen I need to kick off `raisePropertyChanged("Instance")` after the task completes.

I solved it by passing my `raisePropertyChanged` as a delegate and the property name as a string to the implementation class of `INotifyTaskCompletion`.

I am content with this solution, but perhaps I am overlooking something?
**EDIT:**
it turned out that the straightforward way of Mr. Cleary is correct, however only when `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=True`. Otherwise there is no automatic selection of the first item of the list.

Another, related, issue popped up.
I added to `INotifyTaskCompletion` the check `if (propertyChanged == null) throw new Exception("PropertyChanged: no subscribers");` because I have had issues with that before.

Then in the setter of `Instance` I added:

```
private string _instance;
public string Instance
{
  get { return _instance; }
  set
  {
    if (ProjectsAsync == null && !Properties.Settings.Default.Instance.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        value = InstantiesAsync.Result.FirstOrDefault(i => i == Properties.Settings.Default.Instance);
    }
    _instance = value;
    raisePropertyChanged("Instance");
    ProjectsAsync = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetProjetsAsync(value));
  }
}
```

The idea here is to override the default selection of item 0 of the underlying `ICollectionView`.
Then the Exception I mentioned occurs. I have to manipulate the `CurrentItem` of the `ICollectionView` instead of arbitrarily changing the value. Any ideas?

My current solution is to avoid `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=True` altogether and set the SelectedItem of the list when the list is set to a new value.
Therefore I have to subscribe to the async PropertyChanged event:

```
instancesAsync.PropertyChanged += instancesAsync_Ready;
```

And there:

```
if (e.PropertyName == "Result")
    {
       if (instance == null && !Properties.Settings.Default.Instance.IsNullOrEmpty())
       {
           Instance = InstancesAsync.Result.FirstOrDefault(i => i == Properties.Settings.Default.Instance);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite getting how the databinding looks or where the "extra" call to `raisePropertyChanged("Instance")` is. It's not in the code above.

But what *should* work is raising `PropertyChanged` only on your own properties when they change, as such:

```
async Task<ObservableCollection<string>> GetInstancesAsync()
{
  var instances = await TaskEx.Run(() => Agent.GetInstances());
  return new ObservableCollection<string>(instances);
}

private readonly INotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<string>> _instancesAsync;
public INotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<string>> InstancesAsync
{ get { return _instancesAsync; } }

private string _instance;
public string Instance
{
  get { return _instance; }
  set
  {
    _instance = value;
    raisePropertyChanged("Instance");
    ProjectsAsync = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetProjetsAsync(value));
  }
}

private INotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<string>> _projectsAsync;
public INotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<string>> ProjectsAsync
{
  get { return _projectsAsync; }
  set
  {
    _projectsAsync = value;
    raisePropertyChanged("ProjectsAsync");
  }
}
```

Also, there's no need to raise `PropertyChanged` from the constructor.

Comment: You are right, it works. Another, related issue now pops up, perhaps you can have a look at my edited question.

Comment: Remove your `PropertyChanged: no subscribers` exception. If a property changes, it should *not* raise an exception if no one is listening.

Comment: I agree, it was useful for me to pinpoint certain problems where I  changed/created an object e.g. `_instancesAsync` wrongly. Evertything now works perfectly, thanks for the support.